# Service host local system consuming lot of bandwidth

Tags: windows

windows 10 started consuming lot of bandwidth in background updates.

Service host Local system consuming lot of bandwidth. how to stop those background downloads.

Guys, i would really appreciate if anyone able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

After finding/ analyzing all the blogs and post, I got the solution for this,

goto local services.msc and disable all the below services, which consuming lot of bandwidth from your internet.

Windows Update
Adobe Acrobat Update Service
Windows Management Instrumentation
Skype Updater
Team Viewer

http://www.drtuts.com/service-host-local-system-consuming-lot-bandwidth-solved/